# Remote Endpoints option in spfx webpart

Tags: spfx, app, spfx-webparts

In SharePoint hosted app We specify the "Remote Endpoints" in AppManifest.XML file, here is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

Where to add the "Remote Endpoints" in SharePoint framework webpart.? As there is no such AppManifest.XML file.??

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'specify' remote endpoint anywhere in a SPFX webpart project. If you are hosting a remote endpoint in Azure as a webapi in app service or azure function, [this PnP webcast](https://dev.office.com/blogs/calling-external-apis-securely-from-sharepoint-framework) should be a good starter.